# layer rounded corners on a Swift

Tags: swift, cornerradius

I tried to get a rounded corner with layer.cornerRadius  for my segmented control but it does not work for me  actually I want to get cornerRadius depending on the frame

here is my code

```
func setupView(){
    layer.masksToBounds = true

    // here my corner radius 
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2.0
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.walkthroughOrangeAccent.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 2

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    setupImageView()

    addIndividualItemConstraints(items: imageViewList, mainView: self, padding: 0)

    insertSubview(thumbView, at: 0)

}
```

Comment: Your view is probably not initialized yet so has no frame, try to print your frame.height right before assigning your layer.cornerRadius to frame.height / 2.0, I think it will give you 0. You might wanna override layoutSubviews method of your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're not seeing the corner radius because of the layout constraints. Try subclassing the segmented control and setting the corner radius in `layoutSubviews`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2.0
}
```

Or, if you're in the view controller:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    segmentedControl.layer.cornerRadius = segmentedControl.frame.width / 2.0
}
```